# Multi-user e-mail client, with shared tags/replies/footer, for a single email account

Tags: collaboration, email-client

I need a e-mail client even if it is paid, that allow multiple people work on a single account.

For example: when user A tag some e-mail with "process this later", all other users will see that tag too.

Or when a user B replies some e-mail, all other users see the e-mail was replied and what the reply was.

Or when user C edits the automatic footer of the e-mail where people put their company name and whatnot, all users when writing new e-mails get the updated footer already.